# Mistake in the integral of a piece-wise defined function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have to compute:

$\int(\int f(x,y) dx)dy$ where $f(x,y):=  
\begin{cases}
 1 & \text{if }x \geq0,x \leq y < x+1; (1)\\
-1 & \text{if } x \geq0, x+1\leq y < x+2; (2)\\
0 & \text{otherwise}  (3)  
\end{cases}$

I tried to solve it in the following way:

Consider $(1):$ I fixed $y$ and ignored $x \implies 0 \leq  y \leq 1$. Now I consider $y$ as a constant and since $x \geq 0$ and $x \leq y$ it follows that: $0 \leq x \leq y$.

Now look at $(2)$: Again I fix $y$ and ignore $x \implies 1 \leq y \leq2$. Now lookt at $y$ as a constant. Since $x \geq 0$ $\implies$ $1 \leq x+1 \leq y \implies 0 \leq x \leq y-1$

Now I have that:

$\int(\int f(x,y) dx)dy = \int_0^1(\int_0^y1dx)dy + \int_1^2(\int_0^{y-1}(-1)dx)dy$

But I know that I'm missing something. Does anyone see the mistake?

Comment: I do not see an upper bound in the question but your working assumes one.

Comment: @MathLover In which step do I assume that there is one? And how do I have to change my inequalities?

Comment: because the way you have set up integral. For example, the first integral should be $\int_0^{\infty} \ (\int_{y-1}^y 1 \ dx) \ dy$

Comment: @MathLover How can I conclude from my inequalities that the first integral should be that? Are my inequalities wrong?